# cypress react testing a component where you have to be logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress

Hi first time trying to make test in cypress and I have a component called comments you are only allow to make comments if you are logged in as a user. So I what to test that, can I mock a user and set my useState/myCurrentUser? actually its though useContext my user is set.

```
import {Comments} from "../../src/app/risk-modules/risk-pattern-details/components/Comments";

 describe('LoginTest.cy.tsx', () => {

 // set userauth

 it('playground', () => {
   cy.mount(<Comments className={'test'} />)
   cy.get('#mybutton').click();
 })
})
```

how my comments component looks like, where is has a state called hasAccess, the "hasAccess is the one I want to mock, just set that state to true.

```
<div className={`card-toolbar ${!hasAccess && classes.isDisabled}`}>
    <button
       id='mybutton'
     
        data-bs-toggle='modal'
        data-bs-target='#kt_modal_comment'
        disabled={!hasAccess}
        onClick={() => setOpenDialog(!openDialog)}
       >
        New comment
        </button>
      </div>
```

So at the end I want to mock a useContext state called "hasAccess" to true